# Counting "cardinality" of bounded subsets

Tags: general-topology

Imagine that I have a bounded subset $X \subset \mathbb{R}$.

$X = (0,1) \cup (2,3) \cup (4,5) \cup \{9\}$

I want to count the number of intervals + singleton sets that make up $X$. To be clear, another way to get at what I'm asking is through the related set $ Y \subset P(\mathbb{R})$ and its cardinality:

$Y = \{(0,1), (2,3), (4,5), \{9\}\}$

$|Y| = 4$

How do I define a function $f$ to get the 'cardinality' of a set like $X$?. For instance,

$f(X) = 4$

$f(\{0\}\cup\{2\}) = 2$

$f([0,2] \cup \{9\} \cup [12,13) \cup \{17\}) = 4$

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question.  How is $X$ presented?  In your example, $X$ is given as the union of $3$ disjoint intervals, and we just count them.  What is an example that presents some difficulty?

Comment: Sorry, I've clarified my question.

Comment: If you need something different than the following, then you'll need to phrase your question more precisely: Let $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ be the collection of bounded subsets of ${\mathbb R}.$ Given $X \in {\mathcal B}(\mathbb R),$ define $f(X)$ to be the cardinality of the collection of [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Connected_components) of $X.$

Comment: Just state what the function is as you have.  Other than tht There really isn't any other way that I know of.  Note, it could be infinite (Ex.  $X=\cup (\frac 1{n+1},\frac 1n)$) and if you allow singletons as "intervals", as you  did in your examples, it can be uncountable (Ex.  $X = \{x\in(0,1)| x \not \in \mathbb Q\}$.

Comment: Thank you, connected components was the notion I was looking for!